# How to prove that a map is a Kan fibration

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, fibration

For simplicial sets $X$ and $Y$, let us denote by $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X, Y)$ the simplicial set of morphisms $X \to Y$. If $p: X \to Z$ and $q: Y \to Z$ are morphisms of simplicial sets, let us define the simplicial set of morphisms $X \to Y$ over $Z$ (or $p \to q$ in the slice, if you prefer) as the simplicial set $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(p, q)$ given by the pullback of the following corner:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 & &\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X, Y)\\
 & @V{q_\ast}VV\\
\ast @>{p}>> \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X, Z) ;
\end{CD}$$

It is almost obvious that if $q$ is a Kan fibration, then $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(p, q)$ is a Kan complex, as the exponential of a Kan fibration is a Kan fibration, too. What I cannot prove is the following: if $i_A: A\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion of a simplicial subset and $q$ is a Kan fibration, then the restriction map $$ i_A^\ast : \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(p, q) \to \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(p|_A, q)$$ is a Kan fibration. Has anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kan–Quillen model structure on simplicial sets satisifies axiom SM7, which means the canonical morphism
$$[X, Y] \to [A, Y] \times_{[A, Z]} [X, Z]$$
induced by a monomorphism $A \to X$ and a Kan fibration $Y \to Z$ is a Kan fibration.
Consider the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
[p, q] @>>> [p \circ i, q] @>>> \Delta^0 \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
[X, Y] @>>> [A, Y] \times_{[A, Z]} [X, Z] @>>> [X, Z] \\
& @VVV @VVV \\
& &[A, Y] @>>> [A, Z]
\end{CD}$$
The wide rectangle and the tall rectangle are pullbacks by definition.
The bottom right square is a pullback, so the top right square is a pullback, and it follows that the top left square is also a pullback.
Hence, $[p, q] \to [p \circ i, q]$ is a pullback of $[X, Y] \to [A, Y] \times_{[A, Z]} [X, Z]$, so it is indeed a Kan fibration.